# listView isn't updating until I navigate up from the fragment and then go back?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I apologize for the awkward wording of my title, I'm not sure how to succinctly ask this question. I have a listView within a fragment called TaskListFragment. This fragment is started after a user selects a course from CourseListFragment, and it shows a list of tasks for that course. From here, the user can add a task. Upon saving that task, they are brought back to TaskListFragment, where the task does not appear. If you navigate up to get back to CourseListFragment and then select the course again, the task appears in the list. Likewise if I try to delete a task, it still shows in the list until I navigate up and go back again. Any idea why this might be happening?

Below is my TaskListFragment:

```
public class TaskListFragment extends ListFragment {

private ArrayList<Task> mTasks;
private  static String courseName;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    courseName = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    getActivity().setTitle(courseName);
    ArrayList<Task> alltasks = TaskLab.get(getActivity()).getTasks();
    mTasks = filterTasks(alltasks);
    TaskAdapter adapter = new TaskAdapter(mTasks);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private ArrayList<Task> filterTasks(ArrayList<Task> tasks) {
    ArrayList<Task> filteredTasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
    for (Task t: tasks) {
        if (t.getBelongsToCourse().equals(courseName)) {
            filteredTasks.add(t);
        }
    } 
    return filteredTasks;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    //Get the Task from the adapter
    Task t = ((TaskAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position);
    // Start TaskActivity for this task
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), TaskActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(TaskFragment.EXTRA_TASK_ID, t.getId());
    startActivity(i);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_task_list, menu);
} 

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_item_new_task:
        Task task = new Task();
        task.setBelongsToCourse(courseName);
        TaskLab.get(getActivity()).addTask(task);
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), TaskActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(TaskFragment.EXTRA_TASK_ID, task.getId());
        startActivityForResult(i, 0);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.task_list_item_context, menu);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState);
    ListView listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);

    listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                long id, boolean checked) {
            // Required, but not used in this implementation
        }

        // ActionMode.Callback methods
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.task_list_item_context, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
            // Required, but not used in this implementation
        }
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_item_delete_task:
                TaskAdapter adapter = (TaskAdapter)getListAdapter();
                TaskLab taskLab = TaskLab.get(getActivity());
                for (int i = adapter.getCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (getListView().isItemChecked(i)) {
                        taskLab.deleteTask(adapter.getItem(i));
                    }
                }
                mode.finish();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            // Required, but not used in this implementation
        }
    });
    return v;
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
    int position = info.position;
    TaskAdapter adapter = (TaskAdapter)getListAdapter();
    Task task = adapter.getItem(position);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_item_delete_task:
        TaskLab.get(getActivity()).deleteTask(task);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((TaskAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private class TaskAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {

    public TaskAdapter(ArrayList<Task> tasks) {
        super(getActivity(), 0, tasks);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // If we weren't given a view, inflate one
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item_task, null);
        }

        // Configure the view for this Task
        Task t = getItem(position);

        TextView titleTextView =
                (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_list_item_titleTextView);
        titleTextView.setText(t.getTitle());
        TextView dateTextView =
                (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_list_item_dateTextView);
        dateTextView.setText(t.getDate().toString());
        CheckBox completedCheckBox =
                (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_list_item_completedCheckBox);
        completedCheckBox.setChecked(t.isCompleted());
        return convertView;
    }
}
}
```

EDIT: Below is my TaskLab, which is used to add and delete tasks.

```
public class TaskLab {

private static final String TAG = "TaskLab";
private static final String FILENAME = "tasks.json";

private ArrayList<Task> mTasks;
private TaskJSONSerializer mSerializer;

private static TaskLab sTaskLab;
private Context mAppContext;

private TaskLab(Context appContext) {
    mAppContext = appContext;
    mSerializer = new TaskJSONSerializer(mAppContext, FILENAME);

    try {
        mTasks = mSerializer.loadTasks();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mTasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
        Log.e(TAG, "Error loading tasks: ", e);
    }
}

public static TaskLab get(Context c) {
    if (sTaskLab == null) {
        sTaskLab = new TaskLab(c.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return sTaskLab;
}

public void addTask(Task t) {
        mTasks.add(t);
}

public void deleteTask(Task t) {
    mTasks.remove(t);
}

public boolean saveTasks() {
    try {
        mSerializer.saveTasks(mTasks);
        Log.d(TAG, "Tasks saved to file");
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error saving tasks: ", e);
        return false;
    }
}

public ArrayList<Task> getTasks() {
    return mTasks;
}

public Task getTask(UUID id) {
    for (Task t : mTasks) {
        if (t.getId().equals(id)) {
            return t;
        }
    } return null;
}
}
```

Comment: how you are adding the task to the list ?

Comment: When you add the new task you need to update the adapter by calling a method on the `TaskListFragment` which will have to retrieve the list of tasks again.

Comment: RajeshCP, See my edit above.


Luksprog, in my onContentItemSelected() method, adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() is called after deleting the task. Is this what you mean, or how else otherwise should I retrieve the list of tasks again?

Comment: Have you tried doing the super() call on onDestroyActionMode?

Comment: Create a method like this: `public void update() {((TaskAdapter)getListAdapter()).clear(); ArrayList<Task> alltasks = TaskLab.get(getActivity()).getTasks();
    mTasks = filterTasks(alltasks); for (Task t : mTasks) {((TaskAdapter)getListAdapter()).add(t)}`. Call this method when you add or delete a task.